# Splinter Selenium Phantomjs Driver failing on instantiation

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, splinter

I'm trying basic testing with Python + Splinter + Selenium + PhantomJS, but I'm unable to start a phantomjs browser. (Chrome & Firefox drivers work fine though.) When I run:

```
from splinter import Browser

b = Browser('phantomjs')
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 63, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/phantomjs.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.driver = PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=capabilities, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 141, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 199, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 463, in _request
    resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

Also, when I run:

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

I get essentially the same error.

It looks like PhantomJS is using the Remote driver to connect to a remote server, but splinter isn't starting a selenium(?) server for PhantomJS to connect to. I wouldn't mind going into the source code of splinter(?) and changing a few things to make this work. However, I can't pinpoint what would solve this.

Or, do I need to manually start a server for PhantomJS to connect to?

(As a reference, Ruby + Cucumber + Capybara + Poltergeist works fine on my box.)
Here is the configuration of my software.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10

$ pip show splinter | grep Version
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Version: 0.7.3

$ pip show selenium | grep Version
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Version: 2.47.3

$ phantomjs -v
2.0.0

$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.10.5
BuildVersion:   14F27
```

Comment: Just make the following changes in your first line.
Actual answer from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262150/browser-in-python-shows-errors-in-idle/35288612 from splinter.browser import Browser

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share that `phantomjs` + `splinter` work nicely with the following configuration on my machine:

```
~ $ python --version
Python 2.7.11

~ $ pip show splinter | grep Version
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Version: 0.7.3

~ $ pip show selenium | grep Version
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Version: 2.47.3

~ $ phantomjs -v
2.0.0

~ $ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11
BuildVersion:   15A284
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same error. Then I check my /etc/hosts and delete unnecessary localhost alias. And all work.
Check your /etc/hosts

Comment: see Stackoverflow guide how to answer a question.